# Execute shortcode within shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I am using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/worldcurrency/

Shortcode syntax:

```
[worldcurrency cur="EUR" value="25"]
```

However, I'm using Advanced custom fields and the shortcode for custom fields is not being executed within the shortcode for worldcurrency.

```
[worldcurrency curr="[acf field="fl_currency"]" value="25"]
```

Any remedies here?

**Update**
I think I need to be using the

```
add_filter('xx','do_shortcode');
```

somehow?

Comment: Have you attempted to post at the plugin's support page? http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/worldcurrency

Comment: i will but there usually no replies there..

Comment: Did you made any progress on this issue since feb 4/5?

Comment: Hello from year 2021. I don't think we can do shortcode inside shortcode attributes. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133472/allowing-shortcodes-inside-attributes

This question go to here > http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets
That said "The shortcode parser does not accept square brackets within attributes."

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could try [pseudo-changing the priority of your shortcode hook](http://www.viper007bond.com/2009/11/22/wordpress-code-earlier-shortcodes/).

Basically, you force your shortcode to execute before it would normally. That link shows how to execute your shortcode separately - and, more importantly, before - the other shortcodes get implemented.

This works by caching and temporarily removing all existing shortcodes, executing yours, then reestablishing the other shortcodes.

Comment: wouldn't this slow down the web page speed significantly?

Comment: As I said, I haven't tried it, but I don't see anything obvious in the example code that would make a significant difference in speed. As far as I can tell, it simply copies the variable containing the preexisting shortcodes (probably just a simple array), removes them en masse (which shouldn't be a significant slow-down) using `remove_all_shortcodes()`, creates your shortcode, then copies the old shortcodes variable back.

Comment: Just found where WP does the same thing for the `[embed]` shortcode, since it too needs to run earlier. In WP 3.5, in `wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php` line 50 is the method `run_shortcode()`. The example I linked too is nearly identical (including code comments). So it would appear this is *The WordPress Way* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer involves changing the coding of world currency plugin.
Then write the shortcode like this:

```
[worldcurrency value="25"][acf field="fl_currency"][/worldcurrency]
```

In the code for the currency plugin, the value of the custom field will be available through the `$content` field.
Then just set the curr field to `$content` and you should be good to go.

Comment: the value 25 is going to be a custom field as well so this makes things more difficult.

Comment: Making changes in plugins isn't encouraged. When you update the plugin the changes that were made would be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ACF shortcode in source (`api.php`), it just uses the API function `get_field` on the shortcode's `field` attribute.

If you look at the world currency shortcode in source (`worldcurrency.php`), it outputs a span with the `worldcurrency` class and a couple of custom attributes, which then get converted on the user side via javascript.

You could probably [write your own shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that combines the two, using the output of world currency with ACF's `get_field` to fetch the attributes from fields you specify.

Comment: Sounds promising but i dont have the skills to do this on my own I am afraid.