# Allowing shortcodes inside attributes

Tags: shortcode, regex

I want to do a Wikipedia-like infobox for some articles on a WP site. I guess the most logical thing to do it is to use a custom shortcode—one that returns a table-like markup with a fixed order of fields, each with more markup at custom along some conditional stuff for showing or not fields if they are not set, somewhat emulating something like this:

```
 <!--MediaWiki markup-->
 {{infobox-cd
 |name=Abbey Road"
 |cover=[[File:laserdisc.jpg]]
 |artist=[[The Bombay Beach Boys]]
 |country={{flag id=mx}} Argentina<br />{{flag id=dk}} Vanuatu (post-production)
 |rating={{stars no=3}}
 |prev=[[The Wall]]
 |next=[[Born in the U.S.A.]]
 }}
```

Yet I have been blocked from using them in a more literal approach for years due to shortcodes breaking while having brackets inside attributes. It theoretically should work, but doesn't because the shortcode regex stops with the first occurrence of a closing bracket (]) in a shortcode, so in this:

```
[foo bar="[baz /]"]content[/foo]
```

it "outputs":

```
[foo bar="[baz /]
```

I'm not sure how else I can get this markup working or something else with the same goal.

Comment: You can expand the editor with additional custom fields: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, brackets are still not allowed *within* shortcodes, as you can see in the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Square_Brackets). However it's possible to use enclosing shortcodes which will allow to use brackets. Let me demonstrate this:

Shortcode: `[foo bar="No brackets here!"]...use [brackets] here[/foo]`

You can add this kind of shortcode in your `functions.php` like this:

```php
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'foo_shortcode' );
function foo_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'bar' => '',
    ), $atts )
  );
  return '<p>' . $bar . ' ' . $content . '</p>';
}
```

It's also possible to execute the content within the brackets as another shortcode:

Shortcode: `[foo bar="No shortcodes here!"]...use [shortcodes] here[/foo]`

```php
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'execute_foo_shortcode' );
function execute_foo_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'bar' => '',
    ), $atts )
  );
  return '<p>' . $bar . ' ' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
```

But let's keep it simple. Why not adding the brackets within the shortcode itself?

Shortcode: `[foo bar="shortcode"]`

And within your `functions.php`

```php
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'build_foo_shortcode' );
function build_foo_shortcode( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'bar' => '',
    ), $atts )
  );

  if ( isset( $bar ) ) :
    return '<p>' . do_shortcode( '[' . $bar . ']' ) . '</p>';
  endif;
}
```

If you want to stay with your kind of shortcode, you can go around the brackets and add something similar, to recognize and replace it via regex:

Shortcode: `[foo bar="Use your ___shortcode___ here"]`

Within your `functions.php` you can replace `___shortcode___` with `[shortcode]` and again execute it via `do_shortcode()`

```php
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'regex_foo_shortcode' );
function regex_foo_shortcode( $atts ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
      'bar' => '',
    ), $atts )
  );

  if ( isset( $bar ) ) :
    $foo_bar = preg_replace_callback("/(.*)_{3}(.*)_{3}(.*)/", function($m) {
        return $m[1] . do_shortcode('[' . $m[2] . ']') . $m[3];
    }, $bar);
    return '<p>' . $foo_bar . '</p>';
  endif;
}
```

Okay, it's a bit complicated now, isn't it? Another approach (if you don't want to keep doing it via shortcodes) would be custom fields. [Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are available per default and can be toggled via the [Screen Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Panels#Screen_Options).

You can use [the_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_meta) or get it via [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to output them easily within your theme. Moreover it's easier (compared to shortcodes) to handle the in- and output and nobody of the editors has to remember all of those available shortcodes.

You can also generate advanced custom fields easily via [the interface of a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or [build and style them on your own](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box). Anyway you will have nice input fields below or beside your text editor without limitations (even file upload, datepicker...). It will look something like this:

[image]